# Issue While installing Apache Cordova Mac osx

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova

I am having many npm errors in the terminal while installing Apache cordova in my mac. I have also tried sudo npm install -g cordova but it's the same and Cordova is not installed while using Cordova --version

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v4.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! path /Users/macmini/.node/bin/cordova
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall unlink

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/macmini/.node/bin/cordova'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/macmini/.node/bin/cordova']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/macmini/.node/bin/cordova' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/macmini/.node/bin/cordova'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/macmini/.node/bin/cordova']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/Users/macmini/.node/bin/cordova' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/macmini/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: It sounds like all you need is to run with `sudo`: `sudo install -g cordova`. Also, please learn to format your questions properly: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: @mklement0 I tried to run it with     sudo install -g cordova but it doesn't work

Comment: Your setup looks unusual: `npm` is in `usr/local/bin`, yet installing with `-g` in your case tries to install to a _user-specific_ location rather than `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`. Is user `macmini` the user account from which you're trying to install? Check the permissions of target folder `/Users/macmini/.node/bin`. `npm config get prefix` tells you the root of global packages (actual files go into subfolder `lib/node_modules`); use `set` to change it.